# Debugging BULK INSERT Given no Error Message

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am running this query:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.common_player_info_2
FROM 'C:\PATH\common_player_info.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2 -- Skip header row if necessary
)
```

There are no errors but getting the message that 0 rows have been affected.

I have ensured that the path to the file, terminators are correct and changed the datatype of all fields to be varchar(50) to accept all text. Any other things I can check for?

Comment: Consider creating format file (I prefer .xml). Also `format= 'csv'` option may be useful.

Comment: it would help if you have some line of the file and the definition of the table

Comment: You can try to add one more clause: `ERRORFILE = 'error_file_path'`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#errorfile--error_file_path